# Issue with deploying a VueJS app on heroku without backend

Tags: vuejs2, continuous-integration, github-actions, heroku-ci

I've been trying to deploy a basic VueJS app to Heroku without any backend. I've introduced the additional code provided here:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/heroku-review-app-deployment-status?fbclid=IwAR1c9UtTbDLC3sFyyd0CXWk4XvkN9mUVXEqbh7VjHpnXA2uW9XUa91W1uFY

To my YML file for automation, so it's like this :

```
name: CI

on:

 push:
   branches: [ "main" ]
 pull_request:
   branches: [ "main" ]

 build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Heroku Review App Deployment Status
    uses: teamniteo/reviewapps-deploy-status@v1.4.0
```

Is there anything I'm missing because, after linking my heroku created app to the app on my githib repo, I have the application error page

here's my logs:

```
2022-07-11T17:09:26.062281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2022-07-11T17:09:26.062296+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-07-11T17:09:26.062391+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-07-11T17:09:26.064160+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-11T17:09:26.064320+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be 
found in:
2022-07-11T17:09:26.064361+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-07- 
11T17_09_26_012Z-debug-0.log
2022-07-11T17:09:26.200951+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-11T17:09:27.385385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-11T17:09:44.444515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
method=GET path="/" host=my-portfolio-salim.herokuapp.com request_id=996e2ca5-4565-4340- 
b2e3-81e1d46b35e4 fwd="154.243.68.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=https
2022-07-11T17:09:45.669090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=my-portfolio-salim.herokuapp.com 
request_id=7ab2a333-4346-4067-99cf-0f633aa76bdb fwd="154.243.68.33" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a `start` script in your `package.json` file, which is the script used by Heroku to launch your application.